# "the project type is not supported by this installation" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I have installed VS 2008 SP1 on W2k3 OS. After I installed ASP.NET MVC beta and tried creating ASP.NET MVC type project I get the following error.

"the project type is not supported by this installation"

Let me know if you have fixed this issue.

Comment: i have the same problem on windows 7... asp.net mvc RC was previously installed and i installed MVC rtm... the same problem came up

Comment: This is why I hate microsoft crap. It works on my Visual Web developer install - but does not work on visual studio 2008 professional! WTH. Get your stupid web-framework installer right.. .GRRRR

Comment: I would like to comment that there appears to be a number of different causes for this error. In my case I had to reinstall the MVC3 RTM on the build machine (which has been building MVC3 projects for some time now).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC project on VS2010 error : The project type is not supported by this installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563325/mvc-project-on-vs2010-error-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installa)

Answer (score 66):

I tried some of the solutions posted here but still no joy. Finally I replaced the ProjectTypeGuids to this one below in the project file and it loaded fine

`<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

Comment: +1

My type guids were: <ProjectTypeGuids>{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Comment: I installed MVC 1 and this fixed the issue for me (although the project was an MVC 1 project - doh) - I think this ProjectTypeGuids change is just a hack, not the preferred option.

Comment: @Chris Kimpton and @Andrew Matthews - it appears that MVC projects that are upgraded from 1.0 to 2.0 leave the 1.0 projecttypeguid behind.  Simply *removing* {603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0} should be ok.  @Chris Kimpton - in your case, I suspect you didn't have the other two guids present and so adding them was a mistake.

Comment: Installing VS 2010 and SP1 didn't help.  This helped me finally.

Answer (score 16):

I came across something while [having issues of my own](http://cantgrokwontgrok.blogspot.com/2009/03/missing-entity-framework-templates-and.html).

In short, try:

- Run the Visual Studio Command Prompt as Admin.
- Execute:

  ```
  devenv /setup
  ```

It then whirs away for a bit (VS2008 will not open), once the prompt returns fire up VS and all (may) be back to normal.

I came across this when my MVC projects got messed up when trying to get the Entity Framework up and running :)

Comment: In some cases devenv.exe /resetskippkgs might help too

Comment: (/setup requires administrative privileges as it fixes the shared data)

Comment: I had the same issue, but with MSTest Projects.  This sorted it for me too - many thanks & +1.

Comment: Thanks.  This solution fixed an issue with not being able to load web service projects.

Comment: @Rob Cooper,  It says, devenv is not valid. What I suppose to do

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that MVC 2 is not completely backward compatible. Visual Studio cannot open MVC 1 apps without MVC 1 installed. So if you just install MVC 1, which can install together with MVC 2 you should be just fine.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b

Comment: This was my issue. It looks like a number of issues cause this, and ensuring MVC 1 is installed is a good prerequisite.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with MVC v1. Turns out that I hadn't installed the "Visual Web Developer" feature.

This SO user had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404104/asp-net-mvc-1-0-project-type-is-not-supported-on-visual-studio-2008).

Comment: Oh my, had the same problem with MVC 4 RC. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

My situation was slightly different: I was trying to open an existing MVC 3 project. Turns out I didn't have MVC 3, installing it from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Had already reached this conclusion before scrolling down this far, but it warrants a +1. I just re-installed OS & felt pretty dumb when I realized this...

Answer (score 4):

i installed visual web developer from the Visual studio 2008 installation dvd and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 3):

Tried to install ASP.NET MVC 1.0. It works to me.

Answer (score 2):

ewalshe - same thing worked for me.  I know this is an old post, just wanted to put this out there for anybody else.  I had an existing solution in source control (Vault), and wanted to set up my home computer for development.  I installed Visual Studio 2008 at home without the following options:

C++
Visual Basic
Visual Web Developer

When I pulled down the solution from source control, all projects loaded EXCEPT my web project - VS simply did not recognize it.  A fresh installation using the default options and a restart fixed my problem.  I do not have the time nor the desire to really figure out which of the above is necessary for Web Application projects to work... maybe somebody will chime in.

~ryan

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and found this question in a Google search for the answer. Most answers unearthed in the search suggested that old project types were being moved onto a machine with a different version of Visual Studio installed. None of which applied to me.

I've got VS2008 installed on a machine (running 64bit Vista) at work and recently installed the ASP.NET MVC beta, without any problems.

I wanted to replicate my work environment on my Mac, so I installed VS2008 with the ASP.NET MVC beta into a WinXp installation running within a Parallels VM. When I went to create a project with the ASP.NET MVC Web Application template I got the "the project type is not supported by this installation" error.

I finally got things working by yet another reinstall of VS2008 (a clean install, not a repair). This time I choose the default installation options, rather than customising things as I usually do. I normally deselect VB, the mobile device, office and other non C# development stuff - I don't have much free space on my Mac.

After the clean install of VS2008 I did a windows update, installed VS2008 SP1 and finally installed the ASP.NET MVC beta.

It seems that when I customised the VS2008 install, I deselected something essential for the correct operation of the MVC beta. I don't have clue what that something is, I'm just happy that after three days I can play the the MVC stuff at home.

Its been a month since you posted the question. Have you made any progress since?

Comment: thanks; I gave up trying this as I got another new work laptop where where thing is working fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928108/2091951 suggests the missing component is "Visual Web Designer"

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes caused by running a version of Visual Studio which doesn't support MSTest.

Answer (score 1):

This might be obvious, but it fixed it for me. I had installed ASP.NET MVC prior to installing Visual Studio 2008. Once I removed MVC and reinstalled, I no longer had the problem.

Comment: This is what I had to do too.

Answer (score 1):

install ASP.NET MVC 1.0. It works to me.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 if you are not running as the local "Administrator" and have UAC turned on the install will silently fail. The solution is to disable UAC, reboot, and the install should succeed.

Comment: I tried running Visual Web Developer as Admin and was able to open without a re-boot.  Subsequently found UAC wasn't the problem.  Simply open the project from within VWD (I get the non-supported error when I double-click on the .sln from Win Explorer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run an MVC application, try running `AspNetMVC1.msi`. It worked for me, so hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Comment: and where exactly might one find that file?

Answer (score 1):

I kept running into this problem. Running devenv /setup and devenv /resetskippkgs did not work for me. Nor did removing project guids. I installed MVC 1.0 and it still didnt work. Then I installed MVC 2.0 and that seemed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had MVC 2 installed on my machine and I was still getting this error message. I installed MVC 1, no GO. i installed web Developer No GO. I finally uninstalled MVC1 and MVC2 and then reinstalled MVC2: http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&displaylang=en

The re installation of MVC 2 solved the problem for me. Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VS2008; ASP.NET MVC 2 on 64-bit machine receiving the issue:
"the project type is not supported by this installation"

Solution: Thanks to Bert Huijben from above. Under the VS install in the start menu, in the VS Tool folder, ran VS2008 x64 Cmd Prompt. Executed commands:

```
devenv /setup
```

...still project errored and didn't open, then ran

```
devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```

... and then success!

Answer (score 0):

I had to rebuild my development VM to solve this one. Clean install FTW.

Answer (score 0):

Tried @ryan and @Rob Cooper answers with no joy.  Running this in a vhd on Win7.

Zoned in on Mvc and that's where problem lies.  Not 100% but think issue is that I was trying to open a project that didn't have latest Mvc release, which new build had.

Temporary solution is to rollback to previous version of Mvc.  Then when that's happy, upgrade project to latest Mvc and then machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem when I had VS2008 running by accident when I started the ASP.NET MVC install. Closed VS, uninstalled ASP.NET MVC, then reinstalled it and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Vivek Ayer's solution also worked for MbUnit projects.  Additionally, simply deleting the first GUID (rather than replacing it with "{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}") worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Visual Studio 2010 and want to open/create MVC 3 solutions you have to have the Visual Web Developer component of Visual Studio installed.

If you have done a default installation without customization then this component is installed.

If you do a customized installation and say thought you only wanted C# stuff installed you may have unchecked the Visual Web Developer component thinking you didn't need it.  You need it for any MVC development. Simply re-run your VS setup and make sure this component is selected.

The MVC 3 download and installation will work properly even without this component installed. However, you will not be able to open or create a MVC 3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to getting around this problem is the ProjectTypeGUID, but the GUIDS listed elsewhere in this and other posts didn't work for me.

In the end (and this is my suggestion), I created a new MVC project, then open the *.vbProj file and copy out the ProjectTypeGUIDs I found there. When I transposed those into the vbproj file of the project I was having trouble with, everything started working.

In my case (for an existing VS10 VB project), the right GUIDs were:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```