# asp.net mvc 1.0 "project type is not supported" on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I've installed (in this order):
64bit Windows7, 
64bit Visual Studio 2008,
Microsoft Free Web Platform Installer (WEB PI)
- installed iis7
- bunch of samples
- ...
asp.net mvc 1.0
Visual Studio 2008 sp1

When opening an existing solution with mvc web application in it, i get this error:
"The project type is not supported by this installation" on Visual Studio 2008

I've noticed that almost all project templates are stored under "Program Files (x86)" not under "Program Files"...

I've also repaired vs2008, asp.net mvc 1.0 and nothing worked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just some things to try:

Have you updated Visual Studio 2008 to SP1 (google for download - its a bigge)?

Have you removed all previous traces of ASP.Net MVC Beta and RC installs?

Does the project contain MSTest tests and the version you are using does not support MSTest?

How did you install IIS7 (or rather 7.5 on Windows 7)? Did you do this via Add Remove Windows Features, did you enable ASP.Net when you drill into Internet Information Server ?

Can you create a new ASP.Net MVC application does this show in Add New Projects? And copy the Web.config over to the existing one? It may be possible it was created with a previous version and the assembly identies are no longer than same.

When you install Visual Studio 2008 did you untick the Web application bit in the Customize/Advance by any chance (cant recall exact wording) but IIRC it appears as sibling on the branch where Visual C# option is.

Comment: just to add I run same setup, Win7 64bit, VS 2008 and MVC and didnt have an issue although I installed SP1, and everything sequentially post beta/RC

Comment: Yes...I did untick the Web application bit (I thought it was some kind of FrontPage-like jumbo mambo)...and that was the issue...case solved! Thanks