# DotNetOpenAuth MVC samples - project type not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I have an issue with the DotNetOpenAuth sample projects.
I have Visual Studio 2008, with MVC1 installed, yet when i try open the samples.sln the 2 MVC projects fail to load, giving the error:

"Project type not supported"

Is there additional requirements other than VS an MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after posting that question i found a general answer on another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336235/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation-error-asp-net-mvc-vs2008) that worked for me in this specific case.

Changing the GUID's in the project file allowed teh projects to be loaded as part of the solution. No idea why -  don't care cos it works :)

Just posted this answer in case someone else has the issue in DotnetOpenAuth.

Comment: This is because the latest versions of the samples use the ASP.NET MVC 2 GUIDs, since MVC 2 is officially released and available for VS2008.  As you say, it can be downgraded easily enough.  But you might consider installing the MVC 2 project system on VS2008