# MVC project on VS2010 error : The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to open `MVC project` using `VS2010`.
I'm opening this project from `TFS server` but I'm failed to open it 
and getting error : 
`The project type is not supported by this installation.`

please help.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336235/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation-error

Comment: yes i did it. but not working for VS2010 :(

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You basically don't have something installed.  That's why you get this error.  I am very sure that you need to install the VS MVC project type - either MVC 2 or MVC 3.  Use The Web Plaform Installer to install.  The web platform installer can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx.  Once you have installed it (it is only 2MB) you need to search for "MVC", install the MVC 2 and MVC 3 project templates.

Comment: may be but in my project type I'm able to create MVC projects , so is there really missing something to installed?

Comment: is the project in question an MVC 2 or 3 project?  What have you got installed?

Comment: You can add MVC 4 to the list of possible missing installs.

Comment: The currently available tool at that link requires Visual Studio 2015, and it has one monolithic package rather than separate MVC versions.

Answer (score 29):

I got this error when I forgot to select the Web Developer feature in the Visual Studio setup. Unfortunately, the error you mentioned is the only error you get when Visual Studio 2010 is installed without this feature. You can install the Web Developer feature using the Windows control panel.

By popular demand (7+ and counting), I'm placing part of `CodingWithSpike`'s comment here.  Specifically, the procedure to explicitly add `Visual Web Designer` to VS install.

- open Control Panel
- select  `Programs and Features` (or `Add/Remove Programs`)
- choose `Visual Studio`
- click "Uninstall/Change"
- this opens the VS installer in maintenance mode.
- Click `"Next"` once
- Click `"Add or Remove Features"`
- Checkbox `"Visual Web Designer"`
- click `Update` button.
- Enjoy having a working product!

Comment: +1. Great example of where the MS VS and MVC teams needs to get their act together. If the Web Dev feature is required, then the installer needs to install it. But in both MVC3 and MVC4, it doesn't, so right after a fresh install, you get the above error. Anyway, to fix, open Control Panel > Programs and Features (or Add/Remove Programs) > choose Visual Studio > click "Uninstall/Change" > this opens the VS installer in maintenance mode. Click "Next" once > Click "Add or Remove Features" > Checkbox "Visual Web Designer" > click "Update" button. > Enjoy having a working product!

Comment: I had web developer tools installed already (was checked in VS Add/Remove features), but repairing the installation fixed the same problem for me.  Possibly the slew of uninstall/reinstalls I'd done before was to blame.

Comment: Thanks, installing "Visual Web Designer" sorted out my problem, I was struggling with the same problem. Installing "Visual Web Designer" automatically installs ASP.net MVC2.

Answer (score 22):

Edit the project.csproj file and look at the `<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

The GUIDS above includes MVC 3 Tools Update. That's a good guess of what you are missing. You can get MVC 3/TU from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3
BTW, that install includes VS2010 SP1 which is required for the TU edition.

Comment: Adding the `GUID {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}` to my project's .csproj file helped me get the MVC 3 context menus like `Add -> Controller ...`! Thanks for this tip :-)

Comment: This worked for me - replace {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47} with {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}. I tried this suggestion originally by ADDING, but turned out I had to replace it completely.

Comment: THIS is very important step that people forget!

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed Visual Studio 2010 after Visual Studio Web Dev Express and MVC4, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't seem to pick up the MVC 4 templates.  Running the MVC 4 installer again via the Web Platform Installer doesn't fix it.  Repairing the MVC 4 installation fixed it in my case:

1. Under Control Panel, choose Programs/Uninstall a program.
2. Find Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4 and double-click it.
3. The Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4 Setup prompt will appear. Choose Repair.

[Visual Studio 2010 Express to Pro, ASP.NET MVC 4 installed but not an option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496359/visual-studio-2010-express-to-pro-asp-net-mvc-4-installed-but-not-an-option)

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i had opened my VS2010 solution, in vs2012, i was getting the project type is not supported, tried re installing mvc3 as was suggested, cancelled re installation, then i had the issue i couldn't open the project in VS2010 anymore. then tried to re install mcv3 again. solution was, uninstall mcv3, uninstall mcv4, then reinstall mcv3, then i could reopen my project in VS2010 . hope this helps someone!