# The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open an MVC 3 project on my system but I am getting following error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The project file 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\trunk\iCorpNow\iCorpNow.csproj' cannot be opened.

### The project type is not supported by this installation.

### OK   Help

I have both asp.net MVC 2 and asp.net MVc 3 installed on my development machine
I have windows 7 installed on my machine.
I have visual studio 2010 ultimate installed.

Project is developed using asp.net MVc 3 and on Windows server 2008 using Visual studio professional 2010

Please suggest me how to fix this error.

Here are the project types listed in my project file

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the project file somewhere we could take a look at?  That will help us narrow down the problem

Comment: I'm new to Visual Studio, but maybe this can help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vssetup/thread/6f9fba73-6ae0-4a66-a51a-b5ca2918ce9e

Comment: @JaredPar: Should I paste as part of the question ?

Comment: @JaredPar : please find the project file here:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4194299/New%20folder/project%20file/project%20file.txt

Comment: @DotnetSparrow posting the entire file is somewhat wasteful but I'll edit your question to put up the relevant portion of the file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC project on VS2010 error : The project type is not supported by this installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563325/mvc-project-on-vs2010-error-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installa)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your project using Asp.Net MVC4 but you've only installed 2 and 3.  If you install Asp.Net MVC4 it should allow you to open the project.

The way to tell that this is the problem is by examining the GUIDs which are associated with the `ProjectType` entry in the project file.  In this example they are

- `{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}`: C# project
- `{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}`: Web Application
- `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}`: Asp.Net MVC 4

Both C# and Web Application come standard with Visual Studio Pro and above hence the missing piece must be Asp.Net MVC 4

Comment: I have visual studio 2011 preview installed and it is not opening in that as well

Comment: @DotnetSparrow you need to install MVC 4 on both 2010 and 2011 for it to be able to open.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem and I found my answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06cf7bca-982c-44cf-aec9-99cf399b3000/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation

In short:

1. open `Visual Studio Command Prompt`
2. run "`devenv /setup`" from the command line

Also, you must have MVC3 or 4 or whatever is required before you run this command.