# VS2005 to VS2010 project convertion shows "The project type is not supported by this installation"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, project-conversion

I had a project created with VS2005. I converted the project to VS2008 and found Ok. But when i tried to convert the project to VS2010 it shows me "The project type is not supported by this installation". I could not find the exact solution of it though i have tried various different ways. The project using .NET framework 2.0 and PlatformFamilyName is WindowsCE. For detailed analysis i am pasting the content of the VS2005 project file below:-

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{97630F0B-C62D-4135-A1F9-06092B830918}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>NativeMethods</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>NativeMethods</AssemblyName>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <PlatformFamilyName>WindowsCE</PlatformFamilyName>
    <PlatformID>E2BECB1F-8C8C-41ba-B736-9BE7D946A398</PlatformID>
    <OSVersion>5.0</OSVersion>
    <DeployDirSuffix>NativeMethods</DeployDirSuffix>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FormFactorID>
    </FormFactorID>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;$(PlatformFamilyName)</DefineConstants>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;$(PlatformFamilyName)</DefineConstants>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ceddk.cs" />
    <Compile Include="coredll.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v1.0'" Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.v1.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v2.0'" Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}">
        <HostingProcess disable="1" />
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10337114/1064610)

Comment: Support for Windows Mobile projects was completely removed in VS2010.  The last version of Visual Studio that still supports them is VS2008.  You can tell by trying to create a new project from scratch, you'll find the project templates missing.  There's an easy explanation for this, the company name resembles a fruit and starts with the letter A.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 does not support .NET Compact Framework development. The last supported version is Visual Studio 2008.