# Project type not supported: safe to remove GUID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

If I try to open one of my projects in VS2010 on our build machine I get the error: "The project type is not supported by this installation". This is because I don't have MVC 4 installed on this machine. As I would like to keep my build machine as clean as possible I would like NOT to install MVC 4 (and deploy/reference the needed DLLs manually). Is it safe to edit my project file and to remove `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}` (MVC4) from `<ProjectTypeGuids>`?

Comment: i would install mvc4 and make your build machine build it as per normal. You talk about keeping your build machine 'as clean as possible' but you're ok with editing the sln/csproj files by hand? If you remove the mvc4 guid you may lose some features of that project type (i dont have the ref for this)

Comment: I get your objection (and it might be true). However, I'm the 'owner' of the project file but not the 'owner' of the build machine...

Comment: get the owner to install it, ask nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

You would be editing you **solution** file, not the project file in this case.

Well, if it's only you working on this, or you don't check the .sln back into source code once you have removed it, then yes.
If you do, it will be missing for others, who have MVC installed.

Alternatively, leave it in there as unloaded.

Another workaround would be to create a separate SLN file with everything **but** the offending project in.

**EDIT**

You would need MVC installed to be able to open / edit / do anything with this project.

Comment: Why the solution file? It IS part of my csproj-file which is under source control

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the affected project? Can you post your solution layout? not sure i follow your structure...

Comment: I want to remove a project-type which prevents VS from opening my project. The project types are in <ProjectTypeGuids>. I have exactly the same situation as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336827/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation

Comment: Well, I removed the entry just for test purposes: I could open the project on the build machine and edit and compile it as usulal.