# Visual Studio 2010 Express to Pro, ASP.NET MVC 4 installed but not an option?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Windows 7. I originally had Visual Studio 2010 Express, and installed ASP.NET MVC 4 RC. Because I have a student account and required the needs for some Pro features, I installed VS 2010 Professional. However, ASP.NET MVC 4 templates weren't an option.

I used the Web Installer to install ASP.NET MVC 4 and SP1, but the templates still don't show up. I uninstalled Express, and tried re-installing MVC 4 and SP1 again, but still nothing.

Also, there are no MVC 3 templates available either.

How should I proceed? What other information do you need?

Comment: re install all the software..and istall web developer express 2010

Comment: I dont want Express 2010. I want to keep Professional 2010. My last resort is un-installing and re-installing everything. I was hoping there were other alternatives I could test before the last resort.

Comment: try that uninstalling all the version first...then install your pro version...

Comment: Pro is already installed. Uninstall what version first?

Comment: start unistalling your express then  pro .. after then restart your p.c and install only your pro version.

Comment: Oh, right, thats my last resort. I was checking if there were alternatives. I would've thought Express and Pro could work installed side by side.

Comment: yup in some ways..i got some problem also when i installed two version..my ms source safe was not functioning right after i installed the express verion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Under Control Panel, choose `Programs/Uninstall a program`.
2. Find `Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4` and double-click it.
3. The Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4 Setup prompt will appear. Choose `Repair`.

Voilà! Open up VS 2010 Pro, and the MVC 4 template should be listed. On my machine, the repair took about 25 minutes.