# ASP.NET MVC 4 Visual Studio 2010 project templates not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I have downloaded and installed all of the prerequisites for using MVC 4 with VS2010. The VS2010 SP1 update, ASP.NET MVC 4 for VS2010, SSDT for VS2010, and LocalDB. When I go to create a new website in VS2010, there should be an "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" template, but there is not. How can I get the templates so I can start a new MVC 4 website in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 missing ASP.NET projects templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887270/visual-studio-2010-missing-asp-net-projects-templates)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496359/visual-studio-2010-express-to-pro-asp-net-mvc-4-installed-but-not-an-option

Comment: I found this helpful: [Install MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2010 Step By Step](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/install-mvc-4-in-visual-studio-2010-step-by-step/)

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried reinstalling the templates. Follow these directions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116(v=vs.100).aspx

short answer,  [open up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx) visual studio command prompt and type:

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

That should restore all your templates.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. It turns out that the problem was embarrassingly simple: I was trying "File|Create New Web Site...", but I should've been going to "File|Create New Project..." instead. When I did that, the template option I wanted was right there.

Answer (score 4):

Check if Project Templates are installed:

1. Manually search if you find the project template (it would be *.zip) inside %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033
2. If YES, please run devenv.exe /installvstemplates
3. If NO, then its guaranteed that the ProjectTemplates are not installed. You would have to reinstall to get the ProjectTemplates on your disk.

**For the records:**

All the installed project templates are available here: (this is the default path)

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates

This is where the File->New ->Project Dialog loads ProjectTemplates from, and is displayed in the ***Same Folder heirarchy convention***.
You could add another path by updating

> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> User Project
>   Template Location

On studio(devenv.exe) launch/loading it would try to create a ProjectTemplateCache on localappdata or %ProgramFiles% based on whether you are local user or admin.
The cache inside Programfiles are available here

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache

This ProjectTemplateCache directory is Created (if doesnt exists) or Updated(if already exists) by running ***devenv.exe /installvstemplates** on cmd. This command is run during installation of Visual Studio. Ideally all other installers who ship project templates should run this command. But, sometimes this might fail due to access rights. So its is safe to run it again manually.

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887270/visual-studio-2010-missing-asp-net-projects-templates)

> If you didn't install the Visual Web Developer component, the ASP.NET
>   project templates won't be fully installed. Naturally, because the
>   installer then thinks it doesn't need to put them there as ASP.NET is
>   a web development framework.

Comment: I have **some** of the ASP.NET templates. Just none of them are for MVC. I've been using the Visual Web Developer component, so it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install it as Administrator. right click on file and run it as Administrator.

2)  Uninstall it and Install it as administrator again could solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If the install went through fine without errors/warnings/exceptions - 
Try changing the .NET framework on the New Project window, make sure you are viewing .NET framework 4.0 templates.

- PL

Answer (score 0):

Repair MVC 4 installation. It will take care of project template installation

Answer (score 0):

Same as me.
make sure register and activation vs2010 product.if vs not register and not type any key for activation vs You can not ins mvc4 for it.

Please register vs2010 and re-install mvc4.then you can see mvc4 when you create project.