# ASP.NET MVC template does not exist under MS Visual Studio 2010 new project wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed on my Windows machine. I don't want to uninstall it and install VS 2017 yet, cause it may mess with my VS 2010 projects so please do not suggest that.

The problem I have is that ASP.NET MVC does not show under File->New Project-> Installed Templates -> Visual C#-> Web. I have tried the suggestions of this SO question but it did not help: [ASP.NET MVC 4 Visual Studio 2010 project templates not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169968/asp-net-mvc-4-visual-studio-2010-project-templates-not-present) namely reinstall my templates with `devenv /installvstemplates`. I installed sometime ago MVC 2, MVC 3 and MVC 4 using the Web Platform Installer but none of them shows up. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not just install 2017 Community and use that for all your new MVC work.  2010 is nearly a decade old.  I understand keeping it around to work on old projects, but for your new projects you might as well use the best tool for the job

Comment: @maccettura Thanks, will I be able to convert my VS 2010 projects to VS 2017 if I install it?

Comment: They make it pretty easy to import older solutions.  Try it out and see if everything works as expected.  Make sure you keep 2010 installed until you verify though.