# VS 2010 SP1 - The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configuration, guid

I have a visual studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 using a solution where two of my .csproj projects will not open.  The error i get is the project type is not supported by this installation.

It's not a problem with the solution as these projects open with no issue on all other workstations.

My project type guid's are and seem to be the same for both projects that are unavailable within the solution:

{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

I checked all of my prerequisites and they seem to be installed correctly.  I noticed when opening up visual studio sometimes the license name is different.  I'm wondering if there could be a conflict with a previous install?  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: what type of project are you trying to open? Silverlight, MVC or what?

Comment: Can you verify that the TargetFramework is <=4.0? Projects created in VS2012 are compatible with 2010SP1 only if the framework versions match.

Comment: The target framework is 4.0 and silverlight 4 and higher.  The project type is C# mvc csproj and all that they contain are XML maps.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to open an MVC3 project but you just have MVC2

Comment: Well the XML behind the CSProj file state target of 4.0.. the properties in the working project state target 4.5 and silverlight 4.  The XML behind the working CSProj states 4.0 also.

Comment: I tried installing the MVC3 extension, that did not work nor did I really think that I needed it because its not on any of the other working computers that is running the projects.

Comment: MVC3 Extension? You need to install the Framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC project on VS2010 error : The project type is not supported by this installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563325/mvc-project-on-vs2010-error-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your missing Portable Library tools.  Are you sure it's installed?

If not, http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981

Comment: @RichardScott  You're welcome!  I've been there myself and it's frustrating!!  Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the issue is that you're trying to open a project where it's template is not installed in your VS 2010. For example by default VS2010 has no MVC3, MVC4, and Silverlight 5 templates. You need to install them if you want to open their project types.

To download MVC3 or MVC4 installers visit http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: It's MVC2, I am 100% sure.  I have all silverlight 5 extensions installed (toolkit, SDK, and silverlight), also the SDK for 3 and 4.  I have ASP.NET MVC2 and Visual studio tools installed.

Comment: Maybe VS is not accessing some template or extension installed for some reason?  Ive been researching and not sure where to go about seeing this.  I dont think there are details for the not supported solution output in any event log or trace.

Comment: are you sure it's MVC2? Open the web.config file from the project you are trying to open in notepad and check the section <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=X.X.X.X/> and see what's the value of your XXXX