# Unable to open MVC 4 project after uninstall / reinstall of VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

After uninstalling VS 2010 and reinstalling, and then subsequent reinstallation of MVC4, I am unable to open MVC 4 based projects. I get the typical "The project type is not supported by this installation" error.

Edit: My current `ProjectTypeGuids` value is as follows:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace or remove the the ProjectTypeGuids to this one below in the project file if you are sure that installation is correct.

```
{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
```

ref:
["the project type is not supported by this installation" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336235/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation-error)

[MVC project on VS2010 error : The project type is not supported by this installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563325/mvc-project-on-vs2010-error-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installa)

Please check Help Menu >> About Microsoft Visual Studio >> Installed products? Please check whether "Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010" has been installed properly.

Hope these help..

Comment: I'm not sure that the installation is correct, but it shows up in the installed programs list just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem and found the ProjectTypeGuid is having another entry {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};. I have just removed it started loading it from TFS. It start working... Thank you all for the clues.