# MVC 3 is installed but not showing up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

ASP.NET MVC 3 is installed. I know this because of the output.

```
 Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        2015-03-04  10:06 AM            ASP.NET MVC 2
d----        2015-02-22   3:06 AM            ASP.NET MVC 3
d----        2015-02-22   3:03 AM            ASP.NET MVC 4
d----        2015-02-20   2:36 PM            ASP.NET Web Pages
```

When I try to open an MVC 3 project in Visual Studio 2010 Professional, I still receive the "The project type is not supported by this installation."

The project has these three ProjectTypeGuids:

- {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401} **ASP.NET MVC 3.0**
- {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21} **Web Application**
- {fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc} **C#**

I have used the Web Platform Installer to install **ASP.NET MVC 3 (Visual Studio 2010)**.

Further, I have already seen this [The project type is not supported by this installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745988/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation) and tried most of the solutions.

Of note is that I have both Visual Studio 2010 Professional and 2012 installed Professional.

Comment: Which _editions_ of Visual Studio? Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563325/mvc-project-on-vs2010-error-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installa, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336235/the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation-error, and so on?

Comment: I am trying to open the project in Visual Studio 2010. Also, I have both 2010 and 2012 installed. That was already in my question, so I'm not sure about what you're asking.

Comment: Those are versions, not editions. Is it Professional, Express (for Desktop...)? Did you follow the suggestions in the linked questions (there can be multiple problems)? Did you install [ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491) (just installing MVC isn't enough, you also need to install the Visual Studio tools)?